# How to transcode a video to custom resolution using Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder

Tags: ffmpeg, xamarin.android, video-processing, transcoding, android-ffmpeg

I need to transcode a video to 640*480 resolution using Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder. Currently there are 2 available resolutions 720pFormat and 960x540Format. There is a method called `Transcoder For (IMediaFormatStrategy strategy)` available in Transcoder class.

I can create MediaFormat object with MIME Type, Width and Height
by below mentioned code snippet:

```html
MediaFormat obj = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat("video/mp4", 480, 640);
```

but the problem is how can assign it to IMediaFormatStrategy or is there any other way to achieve this.

```html
Piece of code for Transcoding a video:

Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder.For960x540Format().ConvertAsync(inputFile, outputFile, f =>     {       onProgress?.Invoke((int)(f * (double)100), 100);             } );

inputFile: Video file which needs to be transcoded.
outputFile: Resultant file generated after transcoding.
```

For more info you can refer https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I had to do similar, and luckily found how it was made in Java, and then I just had to convert it to C#.

The resulting class (for 640x360) looks like this:

```
public class For640x360Format : Java.Lang.Object, IMediaFormatStrategy
{
    public static int AUDIO_BITRATE_AS_IS = -1;
    public static int AUDIO_CHANNELS_AS_IS = -1;
    static String TAG = "640x360FormatStrategy";
    static int LONGER_LENGTH = 640;
    static int SHORTER_LENGTH = 360;
    static int DEFAULT_VIDEO_BITRATE = 8000 * 1000; // From Nexus 4 Camera in 720p
    int mVideoBitrate;
    int mAudioBitrate;
    int mAudioChannels;

    public For640x360Format ()
    {
        mVideoBitrate = DEFAULT_VIDEO_BITRATE;
        mAudioBitrate = AUDIO_BITRATE_AS_IS;
        mAudioChannels = AUDIO_CHANNELS_AS_IS;
    }

    public For640x360Format (int videoBitrate)
    {
        mVideoBitrate = videoBitrate;
        mAudioBitrate = AUDIO_BITRATE_AS_IS;
        mAudioChannels = AUDIO_CHANNELS_AS_IS;
    }

    public For640x360Format (int videoBitrate, int audioBitrate, int audioChannels)
    {
        mVideoBitrate = videoBitrate;
        mAudioBitrate = audioBitrate;
        mAudioChannels = audioChannels;
    }

    public MediaFormat CreateAudioOutputFormat (MediaFormat inputFormat)
    {
        if (mAudioBitrate == AUDIO_BITRATE_AS_IS || mAudioChannels == AUDIO_CHANNELS_AS_IS) return null;

        // Use original sample rate, as resampling is not supported yet.
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.CreateAudioFormat (MediaFormatExtraConstants.MimetypeAudioAac,
                                                            inputFormat.GetInteger (MediaFormat.KeySampleRate),
                                                            mAudioChannels);
        // this is obsolete: MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC, so using MediaCodecProfileType.Aacobjectlc instead
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyAacProfile, (int)MediaCodecProfileType.Aacobjectlc); 
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, mAudioBitrate);
        return format;
    }

    public MediaFormat CreateVideoOutputFormat (MediaFormat inputFormat)
    {
        int width = inputFormat.GetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyWidth);
        int height = inputFormat.GetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyHeight);
        int longer, shorter, outWidth, outHeight;

        if (width >= height)
        {
            longer = width;
            shorter = height;
            outWidth = LONGER_LENGTH;
            outHeight = SHORTER_LENGTH;
        }
        else
        {
            shorter = width;
            longer = height;
            outWidth = SHORTER_LENGTH;
            outHeight = LONGER_LENGTH;
        }

        if (longer * 9 != shorter * 16)
        {
            throw new OutputFormatUnavailableException ("This video is not 16:9, and is not able to transcode. (" + width + "x" + height + ")");
        }
        if (shorter <= SHORTER_LENGTH)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine ("This video is less or equal to 720p, pass-through. (" + width + "x" + height + ")");
            #endif

            return null;
        }

        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat ("video/avc", outWidth, outHeight);
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, mVideoBitrate);
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, 30);
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 3);
        // this is obsolete: MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLORFormatSurface, so using MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatsurface instead
        format.SetInteger (MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, (int)MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatsurface);

        return format;
    }
}
```

Just change LONGER_LENGTH and SHORTER_LENGTH to whatever resolution you need and, obviously, create a new class for it.
Could probably also just make a generic class that takes in the two lengths, but I haven't had a need for it yet.

[Link to the Java code](https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/net/ypresto/androidtranscoder/format/Android720pFormatStrategy.java)

Comment: Thank you very much for that !